# Play Framework (Java): Debugging 'cannot find symbol: (routes file : line number not found)' error

Tags: playframework

I have a big application with a lot of classes and a big `route` file. After adding the new route, it stopped working and gives me the following error:

> Compilation error
>
> > error: cannot find symbol
> >
> > > In `/home/path..../routes (line number not found)`

Comment: Try `activator clean`

Comment: Your "licenţă" project ;). In any case... when somethin' really weird happens -> clean -> reload -> compile -> ~run

Answer (score 1):

Here I assume that your route definition is correct: pointing to a correct controller with the right signature.

**Recompile**: So in play you need to do a `clean` compile whenever you touch the route file:

```
sbt clean compile
```

This will regenerate the files related to the `route` file and the error will go away.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, `activator clean` is the best solution for this.  Just got this same problem today, and it seems that something just got corrupted in the build path until I cleaned and restarted activator.

You can get the `Clean` function on an activator project from the UI by click the `...` button in the `Build` tab.

Answer (score 0):

Errors with routes can usually be resolved by cleaning and rebuilding. Use `activator clean` or `play clean` to clean the project.
If that does not solve the issue, re-check the routes file. Errors in `routes` file can make it hard for play to figure out reverse routing related imports.